# How to modify configuration files using shell script

Tags: shell, sed, sh, config

I have a .congifg file with the following content.

```
train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: ["train.record-001", 
                 "train.record-002",
                 "train.record-003"]
  }
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: ["test.record-0001"]
  }
}
```

I want to replace the **input_path** of **train_input_reader** with a new file path using a shell script,the content of the file list (train_new.record-001 & train_new.record-002) returned by `ls`, there is my attempt below.

```
datalist=`ls ${dataset_path}train_new.record-*`
sed -i.'org' "/train_input_reader:/n;n;s|^ *input_path:.*|    input_path: [\"$datalist\"]| " ${folder}${config_path}
```

result:

```
train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: ["train_new.record-001, train_new.record-002, "]
                 "train.record-002",
                 "train.record-003"]
  }
}
.....
```

This is not what I expected, I expected that I would get the following results

```
train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: ["train_new.record-001",
                 "train_new.record-002"]
  }
}
.....
```

What should I do? This is my first time using sh.

Comment: I'm curious what your environment is. For instance what shell are you using, on what operating system. For instance, when I try to reproduce your result, I get a complaint from `sed` about unescaped newlines inside the substitute pattern, because `$datalist` has newlines in its value.

Comment: I think you can just define: `input_path: "train_new.record-*"`

Comment: @Erwin This code is tested on macOS. After the successful attempt, it will be deployed on linux. See if you say that it is different under different operating systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=( "$dataset_path"train_new.record-* )     # assign an array "files" to the list of matched files
datalist="\"${files[0]##*/}\""                  # 1st element of the list, dirname removed and enclosed by double quotes
for (( i = 1; i < ${#files[@]}; i++ )); do      # append remaining elements by prepending comma, newline and tabs
    datalist+=$',\\n\t\t"'"${files[$i]##*/}\""
done

sed -i'.org' -E '
:l                                              ;# define a label "l"
N                                               ;# append next line
$!b l                                           ;# go to label "l" unless eof
# now the pattern space holds the entire file
# then perform the replacement across the lines
s|(train_input_reader:[^}]*input_path: *\[)[^]]*|\1'"$datalist"'|' "$folder$config_path"
```

Output:

```
train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: ["train_new.record-001",
                "train_new.record-002"]
  }
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: ["test.record-0001"]
  }
}
```

As you mention you're working with `MacOS`, it is tested with `bash 3.2` on Linux. But I'm not confident about the interoperability of `sed`.

**[Edit]**
Explanation about the regex:

- As `(train_input_reader:[^}]*input_path: *\[)` is enclosed with parentheses,
  the matched substring is reused in the replacement text as `\1`.
- `[^}]*` matches any characters other than `}`. It prevents the longest
  match to the *last* `input_path`.
- `[^]]*` matches zero or more sequence of any characters other than `]`.
  It will match the value of `input_path` enclosed with square brackets
  and will be replaced with
  `datalist`.

Comment: I have tried it on linux and this method works, thanks a lot.
But once input_path is empty `input_path: []`(no space), it doesn't work.
Anyway, I learned a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feecback. I've updated my script to work with the empty `input_path`. The modification is easy: just change `[^]]+` to `[^]]*`. Besides I've added an explanation about the regex. Hope it helps.